# OPENGL Blending function - replacing colors slowly in a layering manner

Tags: opengl

What I am trying to do is add a darker red color with alpha (0.1,0,0,0.2) on top of a bright red (1,0,0,1). For the first layer it works fine, the result is (0.9 ,0 ,0, 1); However when the red value gets to 0.5 it cannot drop below that value.

The first layer is demonstrated with the following equation, and works fine:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
ColorBuffer color = (1,0,0,1)      Bright Red
SourceColor color = (0.1,0,0,0.2)  Dark Red

GL_ONE = 1   ,  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA = 1 - 0.2 = 0.8

Cf = (ColorSource * One) + (ColorBuffer * One Minus Src Alpha);
Cf = ((0.1,0,0)*1 )   +  ((1,0,0) * 0.8);
Cf =   0.1,0,0        +     0.8,0,0;
Cf =   0.9,0,0  // Here is the result
```

Now further down the line after many layers, it will get to a point where the destination color is darker : 0.5, now the color never gets any darker as demonstrated below it starts with 0.5,0,0 , but results in 0.5,0,0:

```
Cf = ((0.1,0,0)*1 )   +  ((0.5,0,0) * 0.8);
Cf =    0.1,0,0       +       0.4,0,0;
Cf =    0.5,0,0
```

Here is the result which means the color buffer has not changed and the color I am overlaying no longer has any effect.

How do I get my dark red to layer until it replaces the bright red?

SIMPLE PROCESSING SKETCH DEMONSTRATING THE PROBLEM - you will notice here I am trying GL_SRC_ALPHA and it still has that problem:

http://studionu.net/files/OPENGL_test.zip

The image below describes the problem on the LEFT on the RIGHT is the desired effect.

[image: red on red issue]

**EDIT HERE IS THE CODE**

So here is my code:

I set up a texture buffer object and attach to a FBO:

```
 'gl.glGenTextures(1, drawTex, 0);    
  gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawTex[0]);
  gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
  gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
  gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA8, 1000, 500, 0, GL.GL_BGRA,    GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);  '

' // Creating FBO.
  gl.glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, drawFBO, 0);
  gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, drawFBO[0]);
  gl.glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawTex[0], 0);
  int stat = gl.glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);
  if (stat != GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT) System.out.println("FBO error");
  gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);'
```

I then Clear the frame buffer:

```
' gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, drawFBO[0]);

  // Drawing to the first color attachement of drawFBO (this is where drawTex is attached to).
  gl.glDrawBuffer(GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);    
  gl.glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 500);

    gl.glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);   

  gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // Unbinding drawFBO. Now drawing to screen again.
  gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);   '
```

Here I Bind the framebuffer and draw into it and I set the color here swell:

```
'  gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, drawFBO[0]);
  // Drawing to the first color attachement of drawFBO (this is where drawTex is attached to).
  gl.glDrawBuffer(GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);    

 // Setting orthographic projection.   
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
  gl.glPushMatrix();      
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  gl.glOrtho(0.0, 1000, 0.0, 500, -100.0, +100.0);
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
 gl.glPushMatrix();   
 gl.glLoadIdentity();

  gl.glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 500);

  gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);


 gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, paintBuffer);
 // gl.glHint (gl.GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, gl.GL_NICEST);    
 // gl.glEnable(gl.GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
 gl.glEnable(gl.GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);

 gl.glEnable(gl.GL_BLEND);      
 gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 gl.glDepthFunc(gl.GL_NICEST);
 gl.glDisable(gl.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
 gl.glAlphaFunc(gl.GL_LESS, 0.01);

 gl.glPointSize(35.0);  

  float kBrushOpacity = 0.05/3.0; 

  println(kBrushOpacity);

  float  colorchange = 1.0;



 if (timer>200) {
   colorchange = 0.5; //////COLOR GETS DARKER
  }

 if (timer>400) {
   //colorchange = 0.2; //////COLOR GETS DARKER AGAIN
 }

  timer++;
 gl.glDisableClientState( gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
  gl.glColor4f(colorchange, 0, 0.0, kBrushOpacity);  
  gl.glBlendFuncSeparate(gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);////////THIS IS THE OPENGL BLEND EQUATION FOR PREMULTIPLIED COLORS



  gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_POINTS, 0, count); //Count tells us how many point exist to be drawn.
 gl.glDisable(gl.GL_BLEND);     //Dont use blend when drawing the texture to screen. Just draw it.

 gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
  gl.glPopMatrix(); 
 gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
 gl.glPopMatrix();    
 // Unbinding drawFBO. Now drawing to screen again.
  gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);   '
```

Here I Draw texture to screen:

```
' gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_POINTS, 0, count); //Count tells us how many point exist to be drawn.
gl.glDisable(gl.GL_BLEND);      //Dont use blend when drawing the texture to screen. Just draw it.

gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPopMatrix(); 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPopMatrix();     
// Unbinding drawFBO. Now drawing to screen again.
gl.glBindFramebufferEXT(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);   

// Setting orthographic projection. 
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glPushMatrix();    
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrtho(0.0, width, 0.0, height, -100.0, +100.0);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPushMatrix();    
gl.glLoadIdentity();

 gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

 // Drawing texture to screen.
 gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
 gl.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);
  gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawTex[0]);
 gl.glTexEnvf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
 gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
gl.glVertex2f(0.0, 0.0);

 gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
 gl.glVertex2f(width, 0.0);

 gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
 gl.glVertex2f(width, height);

 gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
 gl.glVertex2f(0.0, height);
  gl.glEnd();
  gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

  gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
  gl.glPopMatrix(); 
 gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glPopMatrix();   '
```

Answer (score 2):

May I ask why you've chosen GL_ONE as the source factor? The fact that your blend formula has a total multiplication value greater than one means that just blending the same color with itself with brighten it, which you're seeing as you're reaching an equilibrium while trying to darken it.

If you used the more common source factor GL_SRC_ALPHA I think it should behave as you expect. Is there a reason you have not chosen to use it?

If you use GL_SRC_ALPHA and GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA as your source/dest blend factors, you will not get a bias toward brightening the image from performing a blend, because the multiplication factors sum to 1.

EDIT: I disagree that using GL_SRC_ALPHA would still have the same problem. I did a quick mockup of the formula in excel, as you can see below. The value of the blending eventually converges to the source color (0.1f). If you want to converge faster, use a larger src alpha value.

Parameters:

```
Source Red = 0.1
Source Alpha = 0.2
Dest Red = 1.0 (iteration==0), Result[iteration-1] (iteration != 0)
1-Src Alpha = 0.8
Result = Src Red * Src Alpha + Dest Red * One_Minus_Src_Alpha
```

Result:

Columns:

```
0: Iteration
1: Source Red    
2: Source Alpha
3: Dest Red
4: 1-Src Alpha
5: Result

0   1   2   3       4   5
------------------------------------------------
0   0.1 0.2 1.00    0.8 0.82   (0.1 * 0.2 + 1.0  * 0.8 = 0.82)
1   0.1 0.2 0.82    0.8 0.68   (0.1 * 0.2 + 0.82 * 0.8 = 0.68) 
2   0.1 0.2 0.68    0.8 0.56   (etc...)
3   0.1 0.2 0.56    0.8 0.47
4   0.1 0.2 0.47    0.8 0.39
5   0.1 0.2 0.39    0.8 0.34
6   0.1 0.2 0.34    0.8 0.29
7   0.1 0.2 0.29    0.8 0.25
8   0.1 0.2 0.25    0.8 0.22
9   0.1 0.2 0.22    0.8 0.20
10  0.1 0.2 0.20    0.8 0.18
11  0.1 0.2 0.18    0.8 0.16
12  0.1 0.2 0.16    0.8 0.15
13  0.1 0.2 0.15    0.8 0.14
14  0.1 0.2 0.14    0.8 0.13
15  0.1 0.2 0.13    0.8 0.13
16  0.1 0.2 0.13    0.8 0.12
17  0.1 0.2 0.12    0.8 0.12
18  0.1 0.2 0.12    0.8 0.11
19  0.1 0.2 0.11    0.8 0.11
20  0.1 0.2 0.11    0.8 0.11
21  0.1 0.2 0.11    0.8 0.11
22  0.1 0.2 0.11    0.8 0.11
23  0.1 0.2 0.11    0.8 0.10
24  0.1 0.2 0.10    0.8 0.10
25  0.1 0.2 0.10    0.8 0.10
```

Comment: I chose  GL_ONE as my source factor because I dont have any background, so the first bits drawn will not show up since the color buffer is essentially 0 in every respect to RGBA at least thats what it does for me, when I dont have any background. If the background is opaque SRC_ALPHA works to some extent.

Comment: BTW Tim, do you have processing, I can send you a simple sketch replicating the problem? here it is: http://studionu.net/files/OPENGL_test.zip    try it out and let me know. SRC_ALPHA suffers too from this problem as you will see

Comment: I disagree that SRC_ALPHA suffers the same problem, please see my edit (I do not have that software).

Comment: You are correct sir, then something else must be creating this issue...hmm here is an image with the issue except its green, this is using SRC_ALPHA as you suggest. http://www.studionu.nu/files/GLPaint_dark_color.png    Do you use xCode? I could sen you the code

Comment: Just paste code in your post, or use a codepad, that should be enough.  Are you certain that you're doing enough iterations to make it blend? Note that in my example it took about 25 iterations to reach the initial value. You may want to try with a larger src_alpha to converge faster.

Comment: Thanks soooo much for your input, I really appreciate your interest, thanks. I tried a larger src_alpha, after 5 minutes of drawing 1000+ iterations the result is the same. I am going to clean my code up for you and post it in the morning. PS, I have attached an image in my original question showing the issue and the desire effect next to one another.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. I would not expect it to take 1000 iterations, must be something else going on here.

Comment: Hey Tim, I edited my original post with the code, check it out if you have a chance, thanks

Comment: Found the answer.....I worked around the problem without loss in speed. Thanks for all your help, Carson

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use the same method as drawing programs such as GIMP or Photoshop or SKetchbook. They never blend anything new drawn onto the canvas, its simply drawn at the end of each call as a texture quad. So fast you never see it...... Anyway , this worked for me hope it helps others.